# Play framework: javascripts in scala code?

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

If I have a html document with this:

```
 <p onclick="hiho('@name')"> clicky </p>


<script>
    function hiho(namevar){
        var1 = @Names.find.where().eq("name", namevar).findUnique();
        if( var1 != null){
            alert("HIHO");
        }
    }
</script>
```

How do I use the JavaScript variable?

Play won't compile properly because inside

```
var1 = @Names.find.where().eq("name", namevar).findUnique();
```

it cannot find the value of namevar.

Comment: You can't do that. The Scala code is executed on the server, the Javascript core runs on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, pretty straightforward, solution could be:

```
<p onclick="hiho('@name')"> clicky </p>

<script>
    var map = {
        '@name': '@Names.find.where().eq("name", name).findUnique()'
    };

    function hiho(namevar){
        var value = map[namevar];
        if( value != null){
            alert("HIHO: " + value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Supposing that the name variables are strings.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to make an AJAX request back to the server. [This page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJavascriptRouting) talks about that some toward the bottom, and about the routing code you'll need.